# Is there a basex function to randomly erase parts of an XML file?

Tags: xml, random, xquery, basex

I have an XML file with an X number of annotations, and I would like to edit it to have less than X of these, randomly. For practical matters: I have 40 annotations and I would like to end up with only 7, having selected these randomly. Each of my files has a different original number of annotations but I want always to have seven in the end. Each annotation looks like this:

```
  <ndpviewstate id="1">
    <title>1</title>
    <details/>
    <coordformat>nanometers</coordformat>
    <lens>0.480769</lens>
    <x>21841504</x>
    <y>-2550259</y>
    <z>0</z>
    <showtitle>1</showtitle>
    <showhistogram>0</showhistogram>
    <showlineprofile>0</showlineprofile>
    <annotation type="circle" displayname="AnnotateCircle" color="#000000">
      <x>16893748</x>
      <y>79968</y>
      <radius>545000</radius>
      <measuretype>0</measuretype>
    </annotation>
  </ndpviewstate>
```

I am an absolute beginner with XML and BaseX (version 9.4.5) so any help will be welcomed.

Thanks in advance,
Guido

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating XML in BaseX can be done using [XQuery update](https://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Update) and this includes deleting nodes. XQuery update is best fitted to working on databases rather than files. However one can read a file, use [transform with](https://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Update#transform_with) and then save the result

Regarding randomly selecting items: I suggest BaseX's [random module](https://docs.basex.org/wiki/Random_Module)

Putting these together and assuming the annotation elements are all at the same level

```
(: return items from $seq after removing  $max items at random :)
declare function local:excess($seq,$max as xs:integer){
    random:seeded-permutation(random:integer(),$seq)
    =>subsequence($max+1)
};

let $f:=doc(".../file.xml")
let $updated:= $f transform with {   
                   delete node local:excess(/ndpviewstate/annotation,7)
                 }
return $updated
```

Comment: It works! The issue that I had at the beginning is that the branches were swapped: "annotations" should go before "ndpviewstate". Thanks!!!!